# Why a code that used to work fine can crash in C?

Tags: c, string, compiler-errors, crash, segmentation-fault

I wrote a code that help extract a data from specific string.
Example: if the String is "ABCD*"
the code will help me define the index of the last char before "*"

```
char *magicchar;
int IndexofMagicchar =0;
magicchar=strchr(InputData,"*");
IndexofMagicchar = (int)(magicchar - InputData);
```

Now the code works fine until you use an InputData that does not contain a "*"then the service will crash.
The fix was simply to add a simple test on the magicchar variable :

```
char *magicchar;
int IndexofMagicchar =0;
magicchar=strchr(InputData,"*");
if (magicchar!=NULL)            
    IndexofMagicchar = (int)(magicchar - InputData);
```

My question is that the code was working fine even if the Input does not contain a "*" why the crash become systematic ?

Comment: Is `InputData` correctly terminated? Provide a sample of the input that is causing the crash.

Comment: @alex01011 ABCD

Comment: @Mat it does not matter because i do a check on the IndexofMagicchar if it >0 or not , the value (very large negative )

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: First of all, `strchr(InputData, "*")` is wrong. `strchr`'s second argument is **int**. The correct call should be `strchr(InputData, '*')`.

Comment: Did you change the compiler? The compilation switches? The operating system? Other code in the program? Many things can affect this. If the program layout changes, the calculation of `IndexOfMagicchar` could result in a large positive value instead of the negative value you test for. If the compiler changes, the fact that `magicchar - InputData` is not defined when a null pointer has been returned can result in the optimizer transforming your program in a way that caused a crash.

Comment: This program was never working OK as you pass pointer not `char` to the `strchr`

Comment: You didn't get a compiler warning for `magicchar=strchr(InputData,"*");`? Are warnings turned on?

Answer (score 1):

> Now the code works fine until you use an InputData that does not contain a "*"

Not plausible.  As others have commented, the second argument to `strchr()` is an `int`, by which you directly pass the value of the `char` you want to search for.  You are instead passing a pointer to an object containing that value, *i.e.* trying to pass the value indirectly, and that will not work as intended unless by complete accident. It is possible, however, that instead of crashing, such a program simply produces the wrong result.

But let's suppose for the sake of argument that the real code were actually correct in that regard:

```
char *magicchar;
int IndexofMagicchar = 0;
magicchar = strchr(InputData, '*');
IndexofMagicchar = (int) (magicchar - InputData);
```

That code fragment is *still* flawed, because `strchr` returns a null pointer in the event that it does not find the specified character, and pointer difference is not defined when either operand is a null pointer.  It is in fact defined only when both operands point into or just past the end of the same array.  The program crashing is one of the best possible manifestations of the UB resulting from computing that difference. I would be inclined to guess, however, that it is not actually computing the difference that crashes, but rather some later use of the value of `IndexofMagicchar`.

> The fix was simply to add a simple test on the magicchar variable :
>
> ```
> char *magicchar;
> int IndexofMagicchar =0;
> magicchar=strchr(InputData,"*");
> if (magicchar!=NULL)            
>     IndexofMagicchar = (int)(magicchar - InputData);
> ```

And that's an appropriate solution, modulo the wrong-quotes problem.  If `magicchar` is computed as a null pointer then you should not use it as a pointer difference operand.  It also leaves `IndexofMagicchar` with a value that is a valid index into any string, which is probably the key effect with respect to avoiding a crash.

Note, however, that it still risks the program doing the wrong thing later on, because if `strchr` returns a null pointer then the resulting value of `IndexOfMagicchar` is *not* the index of an appearance of `'*'`.  This is perhaps a robustness issue -- perhaps it manifests only if the program receives malformed input, for example.  That's the kind of thing from which security vulnerabilities are made, though the risk profile for your particular program is probably small.

> My question is that the code was working fine even if the Input does not contain a "*" why the crash become systematic ?

I do not accept that the original code was "working fine".  It might not have been crashing, but that's a different thing.  Undefined behavior can manifest as an appearance of working fine, but anything can happen, for any reason or no apparent reason.

As a practical matter, I would be inclined to guess that the original bad code was causing the program to perform an out-of-bounds array access that nevertheless happened to hit accessible memory, and a change elsewhere in the program, or in the compile options, or compiler, or runtime context caused those OOB accesses to start hitting inaccessible memory instead.  The details are immaterial however: the code was wrong, and needed to be fixed.  The second version presented *still* needs to be fixed, even if it is not crashing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use proper types (not `int`)
2. Write safe `strnchr` function
3. Second parameter of the `strchr` is `char` not `char *`. String literals decay to `char *` pointers

```
char *mystrnchr(const char *restrict str, size_t size, int ch)
{
    char *result = NULL;

    while(size && *str != ch && *str) {str++;size--;}
    if(size && *str) result = (char *)str;
    return result;
}

/* somewhere in another function */

char *magicchar;
ptrdiff_t IndexofMagicchar =0;
magicchar=mystrnchr(InputData, size_of_InputData, '*');
if(magicchar)
    IndexofMagicchar = magicchar - InputData;
else {/* handle not found*/ }
```

Comment: To perform like other `str...()` functions, `*str != ch` should be `(unsigned char) *str != (unsigned char) ch` or the like.

Comment: @chux obvious yes len